# Exception calling EJB remote JBOSS 7.1

Tags: java, ejb

I have two Jboss 7.1 final instances running on different hosts.

I try to invoke a service in one host from another host, as shown below:

```
 try {
    final Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();

 props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

            // create the InitialContext
 final Context context = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props);


 CService=(CServiceEJBRemote)context.lookup("ejb:......//(rute)ServiceEJBBean!(rute) ...ServiceEJBRemote");

  // invoke on the bean
  final boolean resp = CService.verificarUsuario(//some parameters...);

            System.out.println("Received greeting: " + resp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

My EJB  is packed in a EAR, and the Webclient is packaged as a WAR. I have placed the "jboss-ejb-client.xml" inside the EAR ( under WEB-INF/classes directory).

When " CService.verificarUsuario(//some parameters...);" is invoked , I get an exception:

No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:global,modulename:pinter,distinctname:pinter-ejb] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1fde5aa

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS7 is secured...meaning, you cannot just connect to it remotely. You must setup security correctly.  This document details it pretty nicely, [EJB Invocations from a Remote Server Instance](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance).

Comment: I resolved the problem placing the "jboss-ejb-client.xml" inside de EAR that contains the war (presentation) and the jar (services).